# JQuery: How to sync scrollbars

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

How do I sync two horizontal scrollbars if I am using two frames or iframes? Thanks!

```
<SCRIPT language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></SCRIPT>
```

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
$("#div1").scroll(function () { 
    $("#div2").scrollTop($("#div1").scrollTop());
    $("#div2").scrollLeft($("#div1").scrollLeft());
});
$("#div2").scroll(function () { 
    $("#div1").scrollTop($("#div2").scrollTop());
    $("#div1").scrollLeft($("#div2").scrollLeft());
});

});
```

```
            <iframe id="div1" SRC="UserQueue_Header.asp?Occasion=<%=Occasion%>&GPL=<%=GPL%>" NAME="UserQueue_Header" width=100%>
                <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
            </iframe>

            <iframe id="div2" SRC="UserQueue_Detail.asp?Occasion=<%=Occasion%>&GPL=<%=GPL%>" NAME="UserQueue_Detail" width=100%>
            </iframe>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me in Firefox but not in IE.

```
<SCRIPT language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></SCRIPT>
<SCRIPT language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="jquery.frameready.js"></SCRIPT>
```

```
$(document).ready(function()

{
// Sync Header Frame with Detail Frame`
$.frameReady( function() {

    var ifr2 = $(window.parent.document.getElementsByName('UserQueue_Detail')).contents();

   $(document).scroll( function(){

         ifr2.scrollLeft($(document).scrollLeft());
    });
  },
  "UserQueue_Header"
);

// Sync Detail Frame with Header Frame
$.frameReady( function() {

    var ifr1 = $(window.parent.document.getElementsByName('UserQueue_Header')).contents();

   $(document).scroll( function(){

         ifr1.scrollLeft($(document).scrollLeft());
    });
  },
  "UserQueue_Detail"
);

});
```

Answer (score 1):

The code is not listening to the scroll event of the content in the iframe. The selector needs to look something like

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
//changed id since div is bad for iframes. :)
$(window).load( function(){
    var ifr1 = $( $('#iframe1').contents() );
    var ifr2 = $( $('#iframe2').contents() );

    ifr1.scroll( function(){ console.log("scroll");
         ifr2.scrollTop(ifr1.scrollTop());
         ifr2.scrollLeft(ifr1.scrollLeft());
    });

    ifr2.scroll( function(){
         ifr1.scrollTop(ifr2.scrollTop());
         ifr1.scrollLeft(ifr2.scrollLeft());
    });
});
</script>


<title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
  <iframe src="test.html" id="iframe1"></iframe>
  <iframe src="test.html" id="iframe2"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Works for me with this simple test page. Edited my original post with full sample code. Might be an issue with the frames not being fully loaded?

Answer (score 1):

**This works for me both in IE and Firefox!**

```
    <SCRIPT language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></SCRIPT>
```

```
$(window).load( function(){

  var ifr1 = $(window.frames[0]);
  var ifr2 = $(window.frames[1]);

  ifr1.scroll( function(){ 

     ifr2.scrollLeft(ifr1.scrollLeft());
  });

  ifr2.scroll( function(){

     ifr1.scrollLeft(ifr2.scrollLeft());
  });
});

<frameset>
    <frame src="test.html"/>
    <frame src="test.html"/>
</frameset>
```